# Breakpoint not stopping, if I comment out the constructor it stops and errors out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I have encountered a very weird thing in Visual Studio.

I have this controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class VehicleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IVehicleService _vehicleService;

    public VehicleController(IVehicleService vehicleService)
    {
        _vehicleService = vehicleService;
    }



    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Make()
    {
        var data = _vehicleService.GetMake(0, 10);

        return Ok(data);
    }
}
}
```

It should return the getAll data from my service, which is to be used and shown using Angular.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
selector: 'app-make',
templateUrl: './make.component.html'
})
export class MakeComponent {
public makes: IMake[];

 constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
http.get<IMake[]>(baseUrl + 'api/Vehicle/Make').subscribe(result => {
  this.makes = result;
}, error => console.error(error));
 }
}

interface IMake {
 Id: number;
 Name: string;
 Abrv: string;
}
```

That's the .ts component file and the html looks like this

```
<table class='table' *ngIf="makes">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Abrv</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let make of makes">
  <td>{{ make.Id }}</td>
  <td>{{ make.Name }}</td>
  <td>{{ make.Abrv }}</td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I've basically just altered the default filed you get while creating an angular project. I assumed it would and should work if I just change it up using my already created services and overall project. I was wrong.

I get an error 500 while trying to run the site, I don't really understand the error but I see that it spits out ""Http failure response for https://localhost:44392/api/Vehicle/Make: 500 OK"

Alright, something is wrong with the controller, so I went and put a breakpoint in the method, it doesn't stop. Put a breakpoint in both the constructor and method, neither stop.
Makes you think the methods aren't being called at all. So I commented out the constructor (knowing it will error out) and put a breakpoint at the start of the method. Lo and behold, it stopped at the breakpoint, if I jump next it will error out since _vehicleService is null.

What on earth in the problem, is the method being called or not? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: It doesn't have a parameterless constructor, that's probably why.

Comment: It shouldn't need one, unless this is ASP.NET MVC 5 or earlier. In which case, he'll need to do a whole bunch of "fun" work to replace the default IControllerFactory with a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are running into an issue trying to resolve an instance of IVehicleService. If it is unable to resolve the required services, you would get a Status 500 response before any of your breakpoints would be hit.

First thing to do would be to verify you have registered IVehicleService in the IServiceCollection during startup.

Comment: I have registered the IVehicleService in startup.cs. I'm not sure if the problem is in the typescript code or something else.

Comment: What is the exact line you use to register IVehicleService in startup.cs? And which of the Configure methods is it in?

Comment: I use `services.AddScoped<IVehicleService, VehicleService>();` in the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: maybe an issue instantiating the VehicleService.  the behavior you are getting is what would happen if the interface wasn't mapped or if the mapped class can't be instantiated for some reason.

Comment: It's also possible that the container can't actually resolve an instance of VehicleService due to a missing dependency.